# Use regex to match everything after hyphen

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to extract titles from news articles. The problem is news sites usually append a hyphen and their company name to the title, so I am trying to make a regex to match the space, hyphen, space and everything after it. For example:

`'Minecraft - Xbox 360 Edition' future mash up packs and Xbox One updates posted - National Video Game News`

matches

`- National Video Game News`

I want to make the regex match the space + hyphen + space and everything after it only if everything after it contains at most 4 words that begin with capital letters. I tried using a negative lookahead to exclude words that start with lowercase:

`\s-\s(?!([a-z]+\s){3,}[a-z]+).*`

But it matches the space, first hyphen and everything after it:

`- Xbox 360 Edition' future mash up packs and Xbox One updates posted - National Video Game News`

I'm not sure what to do here, can someone help?

Answer (score 4):

Why not just write it the normal way without negative lookahead?

```
\s-(\s[A-Z][a-z]+){0,4}$
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm terrible with regex.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using regular expression, just use string manipulation methods to find the last hyphen and extract it from there:

```
string title = "'Minecraft - Xbox 360 Edition' future mash up packs and Xbox One updates posted - National Video Game News";
string name = title.Substring(title.LastIndexOf("-") + 1).Trim();

Console.WriteLine(name); // "National Video Game News"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
(?<Title>'[\w\s-\s\w]+')(?<Name>[\w\s]+)-(?<Publisher>[\s\w]+)
```

Edit: Yep, not what you were looking for. Would this work or are there no ' ' on some of the titles?

```
        var text = new[]
        {
            @"'Minecraft - Xbox 360 Edition' future mash up packs and Xbox One updates posted - National Game News",
            @"'Minecraft - Xbox 360 Edition' future mash up packs and Xbox One updates posted",
            @"'Minecraft Xbox 360 Edition' future mash up packs and Xbox One updates posted"
        };

        var regex = new Regex ("(?<Title>'[\\w\\s-]*')(?<Name>[\\w\\s]+)[-]*(?<Publisher>[\\s\\w]*)");

        foreach (var t in text)
        {
            var matches = regex.Matches (t);

            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Title:\t\t{0}", match.Groups ["Title"].Value.Trim ());
                Console.WriteLine ("Name:\t\t{0}", match.Groups ["Name"].Value.Trim ());
                Console.WriteLine ("Publisher:\t{0}", match.Groups ["Publisher"].Value.Trim ());
                Console.WriteLine ();
            }
        }
```

Output for the 3 different strings:

```
Title:      'Minecraft - Xbox 360 Edition'
Name:       future mash up packs and Xbox One updates posted
Publisher:  National Game News

Title:      'Minecraft - Xbox 360 Edition'
Name:       future mash up packs and Xbox One updates posted
Publisher:  

Title:      'Minecraft Xbox 360 Edition'
Name:       future mash up packs and Xbox One updates posted
Publisher:
```